# I've been living-went back-came back

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

If I'm currently living in London.
Is it correct to say ?

> I've been living  here (London) for 6 months, after that I went back to Italy for two months and then I came back here (London) few days ago

Should I have used the present perfect because the action is finished ?

> I have lived here for 6 months after that I went back to Italy for two months and then I came back here (London) few days ago

Have I used the verbs to go back and come back properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is correct. "have been living" and "have lived" indicate something that starts in the past and continues into the present.

What you wanted to say is (with slight additional paraphrasing):

> I **lived here** for six months, returned to Italy for two months, and came back to London a few days ago.

This simple past tense means the six months' residence is over and done with.

Also correct:

> **I've been living** here off and on for just over eight months.

Here, "have been living" means an ongoing situation, and the "off and on" indicates one or more gaps of unspecified duration.